# Laravel 8 - one to many relationship total count not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Truck and Package table with One to Many relationships.

One truck has many packages and one package belongs to one truck.

I have a `no_of_items` column to display the total number of packages that belong to a particular truck. This is how I define it inside Truck Controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'truck_number'=>'required|unique:trucks',
            'no_of_items',
            'postman_name'=>'required',
            'date_of_operation'=>'required',
            'status'=>'required'
        ]);
        $trucks = new Truck([
            'truck_number' => $request->get('truck_number'),
            'no_of_items' => $request->get('no_of_items'),
            'postman_name' => $request->get('postman_name'),
            'date_of_operation' => $request->get('date_of_operation'),
            'status' => $request->get('status')
        ]);
        $trucks->save();
        return redirect(TRUCK)->with('success', 'Truck Details Saved!');
    }
```

But it doesn't display anything on the `truck/index.blade.php` or anywhere else. Why is that?

My Models:

```php
class Truck extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'truck_id';
    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'no_of_items', 'postman_name', 'date_of_operation', 'status'];
    
     public function Package()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Package::class, 'truck_number');
    }
}

class Package extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'package_id';

    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'package_number', 'destination', 'date_of_operation'];
    
     public function Truck(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }

}
```

`truck/index.blade.php` file:

```php
<table class="table table-striped mt-5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Truck Number</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Postman in Charge</th>
          <th>Operation Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($trucks as $count => $truck)
        <tr>
            <td>{{++$count}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('truck.show',$truck->truck_id)}}">{{$truck->truck_number}}</a></td>
            <td>{{$truck->Package()->count()}}</td>
            <td>{{$truck->postman_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$truck->date_of_operation}}</td>
            <td>{{$truck->status}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ route('truck.edit',$truck->truck_id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <form action="{{ route('truck.destroy', $truck->truck_id)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="text-center">
    <a style="margin: 19px;" href="{{ route('truck.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary bg-success">New Truck Details</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am wondering where did you get this? $request->Package()->count()

Comment: @KevinLoquencio I'm trying to get it from `public function Package(){return $this->hasMany(Package::class, 'truck_number');}` inside the Truck model

Comment: well I did not downvote, anyway I got your point but if you will inspect the code the $request variable is not an instance of a model

Comment: is the number of items came from your form? can you show also your html form?

Comment: @KevinLoquencio sure wait lemme edit my question

Comment: @KevinLoquencio and yes it is coming from HTML form from Package/Create.blade.php

Comment: On a side note: if you have relationships you do not need to manually capture count. And, a package belonging to a particular truck can only exist once the truck model is created. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: yes @user3532758 is right, you need to create first the truck before you can update how many packages on a specific truck

Comment: @user3532758 oh I see.. okay, will look it up. Thank you :)

Comment: @KevinLoquencio okay, what about this, when a truck data had just created, the `no_of_items` is set to zero. is that possible? and when a package is added later on, the `no_of_items` displayed on `truck/index.blade.php` and `truck/show.blade.php` got automatically updated respectively. Can I do that?

Comment: yes you can do that, however if you have Package model you don't need to put a field that will hold the number of packages in truck model, you can just fetch the number of packages using relationship where you can count on how many packages saved on database related to a specific truck

Comment: @KevinLoquencio is this the correct way to fetch the number of packages using relationship?: `{{$truck->Package()->count()}}` I put this code on my `truck/index.blade.php` before but it shows 0.

Comment: can you modify the question and put the truck model and also the package model?

Comment: @KevinLoquencio ok, I have added my models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227315/discussion-between-kevin-loquencio-and-mufida-zuhra).

Comment: @KevinLoquencio okay, thank you so much for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your relationship this way because by default the laravel will refer to the primary id of the model which did not match on your relationship foreign keys

```
public function Package()
{
 return $this->hasMany(Package::class, 'truck_number','truck_number');
}
```